# Woocommerce add click to enlarge under featured image

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using Woocomerce (Wootique) and I'd like to add "Click To Enlarge Image" beneath the featured image on single product page. Text should show beneath image and above the description/reviews tabs.

Can't figure it out? Any ideas? 
http://www.forgottentreasurez.us/product/hand-signed-limited-edition-serigraph-mazal-tov-love/

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There’s an action that you can use to add content below featured images, which can be used before or after product thumbnails. The woocommerce_product_thumbnail action is what will help us out. Let’s add a notice that says, “Click to Enlarge” below the featured image.

We’ll use a function to insert this text as a heading below the featured image. You can add this to your child theme or, even better, a code snippet using the Code Snippet plugin.

```html
function skyverge_add_below_featured_image() {
    echo '<h4 style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px;">Click to Enlarge</h4>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' , 'skyverge_add_below_featured_image', 9 );
```